# Speed of simplifying A*

Tags: python, performance, optimization, a-star, path-finding

I've been trying to optimize my own implementation of the A* search algorithm for a while, and ended up with changing the actual algorithmic part a bit.

I've been wondering if this approach would be faster than regular A* or not. Why, or why not? If so, what reasons are there to use regular A* over this slightly different method?

```
def find_path(a, b):
    seen = set()
    opened = set()

    parent = {}
    distance = {a: path_distance(a, b)}

    while opened:
        node = min(opened, key=lambda x: distance[x])

        if node == end:
            path = []

            while node in parent:
                path.append(node)
                node = parent[node]

            return path

        opened.remove(node)

        for neighbor in node.neighbors:
            if neighbor not in seen:
                seen.add(neighbor)
                opened.add(neighbor)

                parent[neighbor] = node
                distance[neighbor] = pathDistance(neighbor, b)

def path_distance(a, b):
    return sum(y - x for x, y in zip(a.position, b.position))
```

I know about using heap queues, but that isn't the focus of this question.

Comment: *I've been wondering if this approach would be faster than regular A* or not*: Why didn't you just test it?

Comment: Care to explain the changes you made, and the reasoning behind them?

Comment: Also what is “regular A*”? I don’t think there is specific reference implementation.

Comment: I didn't mean "is it faster?" in terms of exact actual numbers, I was more wondering in theoretical terms. Is there any reason to use regular A* over this approach?

Comment: @poke: For example, see the pseudocode on Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*

Comment: @JanneKarila: Instead of using an `opened` _and_ `closed` set, then checking both (slower), it just uses a single `seen` set for checking what has already been taken into account + instead of keeping several heuristic counters, it only prioritizes opened nodes by their exact distance to the goal.

Comment: @Port Pseudo-code is just pseudo-code; that’s not an implementation you can compare some other implementation with. It depends a lot on the underlying data structures etc.

Comment: Never trust the Wikipedia's pseudocode, you don't know where it's been. Their A* is yet another example of a contrived variant of a standard algorithm, where much simpler versions exist. Check out Russell and Norvig for better pseudocode.

Comment: Have you *tested* you algorithm? Does it even *work*?

Comment: Eh, after researching a bit more I guess I don't really understand how A* works. I was under the assumption that it just constantly expands the node closest to the goal until it finds the goal.

Comment: @Port: Well, not exactly, but pretty much, yes. But your algorithm doesn't take the closest one, it takes the *last* one.

Answer (score 2):

The original has an opened set and a closed set. It will check if the neighbor *is* in the closed set, and if that tentative score is higher, then it will skip it. If it is *not* in the opened set, or the tentative score is lower, it will use that as the better path.

You have instead an opened set and a seen set. You check if it is *not* in the seen set, and in that case you will add it to seen, and use it.

This is very different, and is likely to give incorrect results. As far as I can tell your algorithm doesn't result in the shortest path, it will simply always use the last neighbor as path.